# Convert incoming url to physical path and back again

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC4 project where the server needs to generate a new url based on an incoming url from the client. The calculations run using the physical path. So I need to ..

```
1. Given an incomming url (eg http://urlPath/filename.html)  
2. Find the physical directory where this file exists (eg c:/physicalPath/) 
3. Calc the new filename (eg c:/newPhysicalPath/newfileName.html)
4. Convert to new url (eg http://newUrlPath/newfilename.html)
```

I'm getting bewildered by all the helper methods and classes for conversion. Can some one help with a non-fragile way of converting both ways (stages 2 and 4)? (I'm doing this in a model and not a view and I am new to C# so please keep it simple).

Comment: what are you doing with the url's?  are you just trying to redirect them?

Comment: @Matt Bodily, I'm passing them back to the browser via signalR. Its for an embedded system with bespoke content that doesnt have hyper links on the pages so the server has to calculate the urls of teh new pages.

Comment: you said you are passing them back to the browser.  Is that to send them to a different page in the project?  If so the initial url will take them to an action in your controller.  From there you can do a return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller") which will generate the url for you and send them to a different page.  If it is in the same controller you don't need to include the controller part.  I don't know if this helps

Comment: @Matt Bodily, thanks. I need to find the directory that the current urls is in and then find the next file in the sequence and then convert back to a URL. I can use Directory.EnumerateFiles() to get teh list of files in a physical directory. I dont think there is an equivalent for webpages? Hence my needing to convert to a physical path.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the physical Path using

```
string path = Server.MapPath("/")
```